# Extracting and printing data from a string

Tags: c#

Hi I have a string result which is as follow.

```
String result= 
>TxData: 7C,0,7A,10,0,0,4,0,0,0,7B,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\r\n\t
>RxData: 4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,7C,0,*7A*,2D,80,0,*7B*,0,4A,4A,4A,4A\r\n"
```

I just want to check if the string contains **RxData**. traverse that line till I find 7A and 7B. I want to get the data between these 2 characters.
I have written a code but that searches the data for TXdata line.
I know how to get the data between 7A and 7B.
How do I traverse only **rxdata line** and not tx data line.

I use index of method to get the index of 7a and 7b. With this i extract the data in between them.
this code traverses tx data line. I want for rx data line only.

```
if (result.Contains("RxData: "))
{
    foreach (byte word in result)
    {
        index1 = result.IndexOf("7A");
        index2 = result.IndexOf("7B");
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a bit confusing, that `result` is a `string` but in your `foreach` the itteration element is a `byte` ?=!

Comment: "With this i extract the data in between them." I don't see any extracting code. what do you intend to do with the extracted data?

Comment: do you want to get `7A` and `7B` included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I traverse only rxdata line and not tx data line.

Start at the point in the string where `RxData` is written and use [String.SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method to pull the rest of the string.

```
String result =
     "> TxData: 7C,0,7A,10,0,0,4,0,0,0,7B,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\r\n\t"+
     " > RxData: 4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,7C,0,*7A *,2D,80,0,*7B *,0,4A,4A,4A,4A\r\n";

if (result.Contains("RxData"))
{
    int start = result.IndexOf("RxData");
    string rxDataString = result.Substring(start, result.Length - start);
}
```

> I want to get the data between these 2 characters.

You can find the 2 indices and use again the String.SubString method to pull out the string inbetween whithout any loop:

```
start = rxDataString.IndexOf("7A");     
int end = rxDataString.IndexOf("7B");

string dataInBetween = rxDataString.Substring(start, end-start);
```

**EDIT**

This loop will never compile! :

```
foreach (byte word in result)
{
    index1 = result.IndexOf("7A");
    index2 = result.IndexOf("7B");
}
```

when iterating through a `string`, each element is a `char`! not a `byte`!
This loop also does not make much sense, since `IndexOf` will iterate through the entire string to find the index. In your case you would look for the index n-times! with a runtime of `O(n²)`.

You should get the index once, pull aut the substring and then may be use `Split(' ')` to get the elements into an array (depending on your aim). Then it would make sense to iterate over them.

Comment: @dipk11 no problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the string. If the line end is same always you can use

```
var lines = result.Split(\r\n\t);
```

Also you can check if the slit contains "RxData: "

```
for(i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].Contains("RxData: "))
       {
          foreach (byte word in result[1])
          {
               index1[i] = lines[i].IndexOf("7A");
               index2[i] = lines[i].IndexOf("7B");
          }
       } 
}
```

Comment: That won´t even compile.

Answer (score 1):

You may split your string at the new-line and iterate the returning array:

```
var lines = result.Split("\r\n\t");
var rxData = lines.FirstOrDefault(x => c.Contains("RxData"));
if(rcData != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the data (substring) in between these two values you can use many different ways.

As some of the other answers showed you can use `IndexOf`.
`IndexOf` has an overload that takes the starting index to look. So, if you have the `RxData` index you can use it as the starting position for the `indexOf`

So Option 1 is:

```
int rxIdx = result.IndexOf("RxData");
int idx_7A = result.IndexOf("7A", rxIdx);
int idx_7B = result.IndexOf("7B", rxIdx);
string myData = result.Substring(idx_7A, idx_7B - idx_7A + 2); // Including 7A and 7B
string myData = result.Substring(idx_7A + 3,  idx_7B - idx_7A - 4); // Excluding 7A and 7B
```

Option 2 is using a simple RegEx with a capturing group:

```
string myData2 = Regex.Match(result, "(?<=RxData).*(?<RESULT>7A.*7B)")
                      .Groups["RESULT"]
                      .Value; // Including 7A and 7B

string myData2 = Regex.Match(result, "(?<=RxData).*7A,(?<RESULT>.*),7B")
                      .Groups["RESULT"]
                      .Value; // Excluding 7A and 7B
```

You can see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/QIrmBn/2

Answer (score 0):

how about that one-liner with no indexOfs? it get characters between 7A and 7B

```
String result =
    @"> TxData: 7C,0,7A,10,0,0,4,0,0,0,7B,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\r\n\t
      > RxData: 4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,4A,7C,0,*7A *,2D,80,0,*7B *,0,4A,4A,4A,4A\r\n";

string firstLimiter = "7A";
string secondLimiter = "7B";

var answer = string.Join("",
    Regex.Match(
        Regex.Match(result, ".+RxData.+" + firstLimiter + ".+" + secondLimiter + ".+").Value, 
        firstLimiter + ".+" + secondLimiter)
    .Value
    .Skip(2)
    .Reverse()
    .Skip(2)
    .Reverse()
);
```

if `answer` gets reversed then do reverse again at the end.
you can replace `RxData` to `TxData` and it sudden looks at first line

Comment: Wow, obfuscating code without using an obfuscator. Honestly, even *if* that worked /which I didn´t test) it seems quite over-complicated IMHO.

Comment: your comment is also unclear. Please tell me which part is complicated?

Comment: @HimBromBeere i use altervative way to the `indexOf` function because sometimes it is more easy write a one-liner instead of saving everytime  values like indeces as `List` often has O(n) search feature. So I don't think I did something complicated.

Comment: You should definitly introduce some variabes to 1. avoid unneccesary iterations (reversing, skipping, reversing again, skipping again???) and moreover to make it easier to understand what the meaning of your code is. Anyway your code is not really a one-liner only because you force it within one line.

Comment: Btw.: Theres no overload of `string.Join` which accepts a `MatchCollection`, and no overload of `Regex.Match` that excepts a `MatchCollection`. You´re probably missing some `ToString`-calls.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, it does not accept `MatchCollection`. I just edited my post to beautify the code for you to see what type it actually accepts. It is `Reverse()`. So what type does it return? btw, skip, reverse, skip, reverse is for reason.

Comment: @HimBromBeere What is more, you don't even need to test it to see that `string.Join` accepts `Ienumerable<char>`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, but it return `Match` (as you said) which return `.Value` which calls `.Skip(2)` and etc. See edited post.

Comment: Now I got it, your formatting made it quite hard to see which member belongs to which expression. This is why I suggested introducing some variables.

Comment: @HimBromBeere okey, so finally, do you think that use of `IndexOf` is the best way if you need do actions that require to get position?